# How do I set margin/padding of a nested flex display?

Tags: html, css

My main achievement is to obtain something like this picture:

[image: achievment]

so, I need to place three elements (divs) evenly spaced, with yellow and green boxes having about half the height of the red one, considering spaces/paddings.

I'm trying do this using a `flex display` set to `row direction` and the second child of that display is an other `flex display` set to `column direction`, which contains two boxes (divs).

However, correctly, what I am able to get is this:

[image: what i got]

I am able to evenly pad the `row display` by setting `padding` and `margin` of `red box` and `column display`.
But i don't really now how to pad `yellow` and `green` adding only the vertical gap between them without upsetting the grid.

Here's my **html**:

```html
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="box1">
        </div>
    
        <div class="column">
            <div id="box2">
            </div>
        
            <div id="box3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my **css**:

```css
.grid{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#box1{
    background-image: url("./img/red.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    /*width: 50%;*/
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 20vw;
    margin: 10px;
}

.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    /*width: 50%;*/
    flex-grow: 1;

    margin: 10px; /*grid margin*/
    
}

#box2{
    background-image: url("./img/yellow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    width: 100%;
    /*height: 50%;*/
    flex-grow: 1;

}

#box3{
    background-image: url("./img/green.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    width: 100%;
    /*height: 50%;*/
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: margin-top (#box3) / bottom (#box2): 10px; ?

Comment: @VXp Yes, your solution and accepted answer both work

Comment: You can do it with one flex container/parent https://jsfiddle.net/f8bac3zx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `margin-bottom` to your yellow element,

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  /*grid margin*/
}

#box2 {
  background: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* 2 x margin */
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="box1">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div id="box2">
    </div>

    <div id="box3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works. My bad I have not thought about that... Thanks